# Google Colab: How can I mount a particular folder instead of mounting root folder?

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am able to mount Google drive using the code below:

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

But the above mounts the Root folder enabling all file access within the drive.

I want a particular folder in Google drive to to be mounted (for example just the dataset folder). How can I achieve that?

Comment: It would be amazing if google drive supported giving permission to just a sub-tree (`chroot`).

Answer (score 28):

It's not possible to mount a subfolder, only top-level Drive.
You can mount Drive in some out-of-the-way place and then symlink the folder you want someplace more central, e.g.:

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/gdrive')
!ln -s "/gdrive/My Drive/theFolder" "/content/theFolder"
```

Comment: really sad :'( was hoping for a solution

Answer (score 4):

If you have confidential files, you can create a new google login for collab studies, at least until google creates a way to mount the folder and not the entire driver.

Answer (score 0):

its possible , you need get the sharable link and get the id of that particular file and u can do it, looks like https://towardsdatascience.com/different-ways-to-connect-google-drive-to-a-google-colab-notebook-pt-1-de03433d2f7a